# How do I highlight a table row in a github readme file?

Tags: github, readme

I'm trying to highlight a table row or at least change the text color in the row in a readme file. How can I achieve this?

```html
>Websites and resources that help with choices related to colors

| Website&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; | Description |
| ----------------------- | ------------------ |
| [Color Brewer 2](https://colorbrewer2.org/)| The original color palette generator, also supporting color blindness. Probably the scientifically best option. Also probably not the prettiest. |
| [Colormind.io](http://colormind.io)| Color palette generator |
| [ColorCurves.app](https://colorcurves.app)| Color palette generator that uses curves to generate color palettes |
| [Coolors](https://coolors.co)| Create the perfect palette or get inspired by thousands of beautiful color schemes |
| [HTML Color Codes](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/)| Get HTML color codes, Hex color codes, RGB and HSL values with our color picker, color chart and HTML color names |
| [Colors & Fonts](https://www.colorsandfonts.com/)| A curated library of colors, fonts and resources |
```

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your table markdown, please?

Comment: @Schwern, it's been updated thank you for your help